# AngularJS Module Dilemma - Single or Multiple

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-module

**For a mid sized application** I'm developing, and having watched the [Best Practices video by Misko](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=2060s) among other articles, **I have deduced that I don't need more than one module**.

Questions first, arguments to follow. In the video Misko vaguely hints that modules might be better for Unit Testing, but does not elaborate on it.

- **Is having a single module approach actually going to hinder any form of testing: Unit, E2E, etc?**
- **Is there something glaringly obvious that I am missing out?**

For the application, the only real benefit I could deduce at this time was *Component reuse*, while there being a couple more expected in future releases:

- Lazy Loading
- Visual Namespacing

These future ones can be safely assumed to not be of major concern just now as they can be easily remedied with minimal mods when the time comes.

The product and it's components being internal use only, I don't even have a use for component reusability in the public domain scale that most articles point out. *Yes* I am organising it all correctly, and *Yes* there is just the right balance of dependence, but I do not see *why each or most should have their own module*.

The questions I found here either discuss the modularisation too vaguely or simply theoretically. My question is more directed at what happens when we don't modularise, as the video suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-modules are good, but you start creating modules and more modules and your list of dependencies starts to grow up and you end having to load modules in a lot of places and it gets hairy soon (In my experience).

At the end of the day, Angular will load all of them so Angular itself doesn't care that much.

A single module is a good idea too.

For testing, you don't have to worry. On a test you need to load the module which holds the component you are testing, so it wouldn't matter if you load `app`, or `myawesomedirective`.

And finally, since this world isn't black or white, you could put everything under the same module, but if you see yourself writing a directive (or something else) that you clearly see that you want to use in other places, you could put a new module for it.